# Could not draw a diagram on the bpmn diagram

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, canvas

I am used webdriver-java to draw a diagram in [BPMN](https://demo.bpmn.io/new) with below source code which just clicks on the rectangle and move to the right side of the circle but it is not moving this shape to right-side of the circle. Could anyone help check what is the problem here?

```
public void createModbusTask() {
    WebElement btnCreateModbusTask_ = driver.findElement(btnCreateModbusTask);
    Actions actionBuilder = new Actions(driver);
    Action drawOnCanvas = actionBuilder
            .click(btnCreateModbusTask_)  // Click on rectangle
            .moveByOffset(493, 159) // move rectangle to other place on the right-side of circle`
            .click()
            .release()
            .build();
    drawOnCanvas.perform();
}
```

Comment: May you elaborate a bit on what error message you are getting?